# A regular expression for harvesting include and require directives

Tags: java, php, regex, file

I am trying to harvest all inclusion directives from a PHP file using **a regular expression (in Java).**

The expression should pick up only those which have file names expressed as **unconcatenated string literals.** Ones with constants or variables are not necessary.

Detection should work for both single and double quotes, `include`-s and `require`-s, plus the additional trickery with `_once` and last but not least, both keyword- and function-style invocations.

A rough input sample:

```
<?php

require('a.php');
require 'b.php';
require("c.php");
require "d.php";

include('e.php');
include 'f.php';
include("g.php");
include "h.php";

require_once('i.php');
require_once 'j.php';
require_once("k.php");
require_once "l.php";

include_once('m.php');
include_once 'n.php';
include_once("o.php");
include_once "p.php";

?>
```

And output:

```
["a.php","b.php","c.php","d.php","f.php","g.php","h.php","i.php","j.php","k.php","l.php","m.php","n.php","o.php","p.php"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you mean by "keyword- and function-style invocations".

Comment: @eykanal: he means the difference between `require 'file';` and `require('file');`, notice the difference in `()`'s

Comment: Might I ask where you use this for? Might be there is a better solution for this then scanning through files with all the hassle it brings.

Comment: What language are you using to scrape the filenames? (I ask because it makes a difference.) e.g. My PHP solution below utilizes the "branch reset" construct which is not recognized by most regex engines.

Comment: what about `include_once('m\'n\'m\'s.php');` ?

Comment: @hakre: Good point. However in this particular case it can be ignored since source code file names containing quotes are fairly esoteric.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031809/saving-a-php-file-and-saving-the-includes-too-possibly/2064502#2064502

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this accurately, you really need to fully parse the PHP source code. This is because the text sequence: `require('a.php');` can appear in places where it is not really an include at all - such as in comments, strings and HTML markup. For example, the following are NOT real PHP includes, but will be matched by the regex:

```php
<?php // Examples where a regex solution gets false positives:
    /* PHP multi-line comment with: require('a.php'); */
    // PHP single-line comment with: require('a.php');
    $str = "double quoted string with: require('a.php');";
    $str = 'single quoted string with: require("a.php");';
?>
    <p>HTML paragraph with: require('a.php');</p>
```

That said, if you are happy with getting a few false positives, the following single regex solution will do a pretty good job of scraping all the filenames from all the PHP include variations:

```php
// Get all filenames from PHP include variations and return in array.
function getIncludes($text) {
    $count = preg_match_all('/
        # Match PHP include variations with single string literal filename.
        \b              # Anchor to word boundary.
        (?:             # Group for include variation alternatives.
          include       # Either "include"
        | require       # or "require"
        )               # End group of include variation alternatives.
        (?:_once)?      # Either one may be the "once" variation.
        \s*             # Optional whitespace.
        (               # $1: Optional opening parentheses.
          \(            # Literal open parentheses,
          \s*           # followed by optional whitespace.
        )?              # End $1: Optional opening parentheses.
        (?|             # "Branch reset" group of filename alts.
          \'([^\']+)\'  # Either $2{1]: Single quoted filename,
        | "([^"]+)"     # or $2{2]: Double quoted filename.
        )               # End branch reset group of filename alts.
        (?(1)           # If there were opening parentheses,
          \s*           # then allow optional whitespace
          \)            # followed by the closing parentheses.
        )               # End group $1 if conditional.
        \s*             # End statement with optional whitespace
        ;               # followed by semi-colon.
        /ix', $text, $matches);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $filenames = $matches[2];
    } else {
        $filenames = array();
    }
    return $filenames;
}
```

**Additional 2011-07-24** It turns out the OP wants a solution in *Java* not PHP. Here is a tested Java program which is nearly identical. Note that I am not a Java expert and don't know how to dynamically size an array. Thus, the solution below (crudely) sets a fixed size array (100) to hold the array of filenames.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    // Set maximum size of array of filenames.
    public static final int MAX_NAMES = 100;
    // Get all filenames from PHP include variations and return in array.
    public static String[] getIncludes(String text)
    {
        int count = 0;                          // Count of filenames.
        String filenames[] = new String[MAX_NAMES];
        String filename;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "# Match include variations with single string filename. \n" +
            "\\b             # Anchor to word boundary.              \n" +
            "(?:             # Group include variation alternatives. \n" +
            "  include       # Either 'include',                     \n" +
            "| require       # or 'require'.                         \n" +
            ")               # End group of include variation alts.  \n" +
            "(?:_once)?      # Either one may have '_once' suffix.   \n" +
            "\\s*            # Optional whitespace.                  \n" +
            "(?:             # Group for optional opening paren.     \n" +
            "  \\(           # Literal open parentheses,             \n" +
            "  \\s*          # followed by optional whitespace.      \n" +
            ")?              # Opening parentheses are optional.     \n" +
            "(?:             # Group for filename alternatives.      \n" +
            "  '([^']+)'     # $1: Either a single quoted filename,  \n" +
            "| \"([^\"]+)\"  # or $2: a double quoted filename.      \n" +
            ")               # End group of filename alternativess.  \n" +
            "(?:             # Group for optional closing paren.     \n" +
            "  \\s*          # Optional whitespace,                  \n" +
            "  \\)           # followed by the closing parentheses.  \n" +
            ")?              # Closing parentheses is optional .     \n" +
            "\\s*            # End statement with optional ws,       \n" +
            ";               # followed by a semi-colon.               ",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while (m.find() && count < MAX_NAMES) {
            // The filename is in either $1 or $2
            if (m.group(1) != null) filename = m.group(1);
            else                    filename = m.group(2);
            // Add this filename to array of filenames.
            filenames[count++] = filename;
        }
        return filenames;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Test string full of various PHP include statements.
        String text = "<?php\n"+
            "\n"+
            "require('a.php');\n"+
            "require 'b.php';\n"+
            "require(\"c.php\");\n"+
            "require \"d.php\";\n"+
            "\n"+
            "include('e.php');\n"+
            "include 'f.php';\n"+
            "include(\"g.php\");\n"+
            "include \"h.php\";\n"+
            "\n"+
            "require_once('i.php');\n"+
            "require_once 'j.php';\n"+
            "require_once(\"k.php\");\n"+
            "require_once \"l.php\";\n"+
            "\n"+
            "include_once('m.php');\n"+
            "include_once 'n.php';\n"+
            "include_once(\"o.php\");\n"+
            "include_once \"p.php\";\n"+
            "\n"+
            "?>\n";
        String filenames[] = getIncludes(text);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES && filenames[i] != null; i++) {
            System.out.print(filenames[i] +"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ~@ridgerunner: False positives are okay since the code will be checking their existence in the filesystem anyway. But if this regexp uses PHP specific gimmicks then it might be a problem since scanning is done in Java.

Comment: @Saul: You really should clearly specify in your question the language of the regex engine you are working with. I spent quite a bit of time putting together and refining this (useless) PHP solution. The problem can be solved using Java but the regex will need to be re-factored. I'm working on this now...

Comment: ~@ridgerunner: Sorry about that; it didn't occur to me that PCRE isn't so uniform over different platforms after all.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`token_get_all`](https://www.php.net/token_get_all). It's safe and won't give you headaches.
There is also PEAR's [PHP_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser/redirected) if you require userland code.

Comment: @David - erm no. The manual does not mention anything about Zend.

Comment: @wonk0 erm yes it does. "token_get_all() parses the given source string into PHP language tokens using the Zend engine's lexical scanner."

Comment: -1; I asked for a regular expression because I can't use PHP for parsing in this particular case.

Comment: It will work with any PHP: "No external libraries are needed to build this extension." -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.requirements.php

Comment: @wonk0 I said I can't use PHP. I am parsing PHP source files in another language.

Comment: @Saul - yes, I understood that; but there may be others who want to achieve the same using PHP, and for them token_get_all is - IMO - the best choice. Thus I wanted to point out that it does not require anything special.

Comment: @wonk0 - True but I think that part would be best served in a more general question which does not target regular expressions.

Comment: Well, just because you *ask* for regular expressions does not mean you really *want* them. In your case it seems you know what you are doing, but there might be others who start off with the idea to solve this problem with RE and end up with finding a much better solution; just like in my favorite bash quote: http://bash.org/?741908. But I guess you are right, we should finish this discussion.

Comment: @Saul: There is a php engine for java available, should come with a scanner as well.

Answer (score 5):

`/(?:require|include)(?:_once)?[( ]['"](.*)\.php['"]\)?;/`

Should work for all cases you've specified, and captures only the filename without the extension

Test script:

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT
require('a.php');
require 'b.php';
require("c.php");
require "d.php";

include('e.php');
include 'f.php';
include("g.php");
include "h.php";

require_once('i.php');
require_once 'j.php';
require_once("k.php");
require_once "l.php";

include_once('m.php');
include_once 'n.php';
include_once("o.php");
include_once "p.php";

EOT;

$re = '/(?:require|include)(?:_once)?[( ][\'"](.*)\.php[\'"]\)?;/';
$result = array();

preg_match_all($re, $text, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

To get the filenames like you wanted, read `$results[1]`

I should probably point that I too am partial to cweiske's answer, and that unless you really just want an exercise in regular expressions (or want to do this say using grep), then you should use the tokenizer.

Comment: It's good but it fails for `include_once "p.".$test."php"; include_once "p.".const."php"; include_once "p."."php";` which it should not pick up.. any ideas how to work around those?

Comment: @Saul Are you sure? I ran the above test script, but changed the $text variable so that it contains those, and it outputted nothing.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that file extensions are also needed so instead of the original one I went with `/(?:require|include)(?:_once)?[( ][\'"](.*)[\'"]\)?;/` (by removing `\.php`).

Answer (score 1):

The following should work pretty well:

```
/^(require|include)(_once)?(\(\s+)("|')(.*?)("|')(\)|\s+);$/
```

You'll want the fourth captured group.

Comment: _if_ going this route, do lob some `\s*`'s in there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(require|include|require_once|include_once)\b(\(| )(\'|")(.+)\.php(\'|")\)?;/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[4];
```